# Directives, requires, angular js

Tags: angularjs

Got two directives. One is a "subdirective"

Main:

```
 .directive('materialDropdown', function() {
    // Input to directive
    return {
      scope: {
        //'personalDb': '=',
      },
      transclude: true,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true,
      controller: function(){
        console.log('material directive fires')

      },
      template: '<select></select>',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(){}
    };
```

});

sub:

```
.directive('materialSizeDropdown', function() {
    // Input to directive
    return {
      require: '^^materialDropdown',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      transclude: true,
      bindToController: true,
      controller: function(){
        console.log('hello')
      },
      template: '<h1>fire</h1>',
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(){}
    };
```

Markup:

```
  <material-dropdown>
    <material-size-dropdown></material-size-dropdown>
  </material-dropdown>
```

The materialSizeDropdown is not shown in the markup, and the controller is not fired either.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I haven't used directives that much myself, but in your require just use 'materialDropdown' instead of '^^materialDropdown'.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `template` option on your `materialDropdown` directive which will use for rendering. So your nested directive will never shown. And a `<h1>` in a `<select>` would not be valid.